# How to set a base url/domain to html string using Html.fromHtml?

Tags: android, html, textview

The url in the anchor tag comes in without the domain specified like this:

```
<a href="/food/sushi">Sushi</a>
```

The anchor tag in the TextView won't open the url without the domain when doing:

```
tvMyHtml.text = Html.fromHtml("<a href="/food/sushi">Sushi</a>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

How can I set a default domain for any anchor tag when calling the `Html.fromHtml`? So it will automatically append a domain to the anchor tag that doesn't have a domain specified.

For example, if the domain is

```
http://www.my-restaurant.com
```

I want this domain to be appended to all the anchor tags in the html string.

Comment: Is this for inter app deep link ?

Comment: no, it should open a default web browser

Comment: If it should open the browser the you can provide a fully qualified URL in  `href`. Whats wrong with that .

Comment: yes, it will work if the provided the href value already has the domain. My question is if that's not provided, is there a way to set a default one?

Comment: Well i don't think its possible . Cause the anchor tag will be processed internally and it will try to open whatever inside `href`. Can we override this behaviour ? I don't know .